# Criteria API - IN clause for Expression<List<T>>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My potentialDonorFile has got an elementCollection causesOfDeath and I'd like to filter on them.

So I've got a screen which gives me one causeOfDeath and I'd like to retrieve all the PotentialDonorFiles that contain the causeOfDeath I've searched with.

I can't really get it to work.. What I've tried so far:

```
Expression<List<CauseOfDeath>> listExpression = potentialDonorFileRoot.get(PotentialDonorFile_.causesOfDeath);
filterCondition = getInPredicateForStringExpression(searchCriteria.getCauseOfDeath(), cb, listExpression, filterCondition);


public <T extends Enum> Predicate getInPredicateForStringExpression(String filterValue, CriteriaBuilder cb, Expression<List<T>> expressions, Predicate filterCondition) {
     return cb.and(filterCondition, expressions.in(filterValue));
}
```

but when I do this I'm always getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [UNDER_MAXIMUM_THERAPY] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection]
```

'UNDER_MAXIMUM_THERAPY' is a certain cause of death (my filter value).

The question actually is, how could I write the following SQL with usage of the criteria api:

```
select * from POTENTIAL_DONOR_FILE pdf, CAUSES_OF_DEATH cod
where cod.PDF_ID = pdf.ID AND  cod.CAUSE_OF_DEATH = 'UNDER_MAXIMUM_THERAPY';
```

CauseOfDeath declaration in PotentialDonorFile (it's an enum):

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "CAUSES_OF_DEATH",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = PDF_ID_JOIN_COLUMN_NAME))
@Column(name = "CAUSE_OF_DEATH")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<CauseOfDeath> causesOfDeath;
```

I've tried using a SubQuery, but then realized that it can't be used since CauseOfDeath is no entity.

Comment: Would have thought the JPQL equivalent should be "SELECT f FROM PotentialDonorFile f WHERE :causeParam MEMBER OF f.causesOfDeath". That should lead to the Criteria "solution"

Comment: @NeilStockton I've just found that indeed. But I'm creating another SO question because that gives me an unexpected end of subtree

Comment: See; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748700/criteria-api-with-ismember-gives-unexpected-end-of-subtree-for-elementcollecti