# Criteria API with isMember() gives unexpected end of subtree for elementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get the following HQL to work with the criteria API:

```
SELECT f FROM PotentialDonorFile f WHERE :causeParam MEMBER OF f.causesOfDeath
```

But when I do that I'm always getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select generatedAlias0 from be.fgov.health.gift.action.domain.potentialdonorfile.PotentialDonorFile as generatedAlias0 where ( 1=1 ) and ( :param0 member of generatedAlias0.causesOfDeath ) order by generatedAlias0.modificationDate asc]
```

My case:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POTENTIAL_DONOR_FILE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = Domain.SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = "PDF_SEQUENCE")
//Domain contains the Id
public class PotentialDonorFile extends Domain {

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @CollectionTable(name = "CAUSES_OF_DEATH",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = PDF_ID_JOIN_COLUMN_NAME))
   @Column(name = "CAUSE_OF_DEATH")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
   private List<CauseOfDeath> causesOfDeath;

}
```

code:

```
 Predicate filterCondition = cb.conjunction();

 Expression<List<CauseOfDeath>> listExpression = potentialDonorFileRoot.get(PotentialDonorFile_.causesOfDeath);
 filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.isMember(CauseOfDeath.AUTHANASIA_CASE, listExpression));

 cq.where(filterCondition);
```

using jBoss 7.1.1

even the HQL query itself seems to be throwing the same exception.. Just found https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5209 and can't update my hibernate version.. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I've changed to code to use native SQL. Ofcourse this isn't a perfect solution. If anyone knows a workaround, please answer..